# Handle the warnings and notices in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array

```
   $array = [$element1,$element2,$element3...];
```

I have a php script which does particular tasks(Scraping) on each element of the array

```
foreach($array as $element){
 //scrape data for each element
  }
```

This script throws many errors, I want to know for which particular element of the array it is throwing those errors
If I run the script in the browser I can simply echo the element name, Something like this

```
foreach($array as $element){
  echo $element;
  //scrape data for element
  }
```

So by the above method, I can know which element is throwing the error, Because the element name will print out on the screen before the errors.

But I want to run the script via cron, So i think the only possible way to track the errors is to return an array of errors in the end of the script (and send that in JSON form via email)

For example: if the script throws errors for element3 and element5.. it should return an array in the end of the script

```
$errors_array = [element3=> ['warning:...','notice:...'], element5=>['warning:...']]
```

I think I can use this array to get notified about the errors via email (or dump these errors in some file)

Thanks

Comment: what kinda errors? should fix the errors rather than mailing them

Comment: Check that element `!empty` it fixes the all notice errors

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam  It is a long script,  It is very difficult to check for each error manually, There would be too many "if" conditions in that case.

Comment: Okay, enable the errors in php, that will create the error log , then send it to email if error log is not empty on every cron request

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam How would we know for which element those errors were thrown?

Comment: Check my answer, it will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

> If I run the script in the browser I can simply echo the element name ... But I want to run the script via cron, So i think the only possible way to track the errors is to return an array of errors in the end of the script

You can very easily capture exactly the same output you would be sending to the browser into a file when you run it under cron. The trick is that you need to redirect both "Standard Error" and "Standard Output" to the same file. The command (which you can test by running manually on the command-line) will look something like this:

```
php /path/to/my/script.php some args 2>&1 >/path/to/my/output.log
```

The `>file` part is redirecting standard output; the `2>&1` adds standard error into the same output file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this, Btw  sometimes the foreach loop doesn't echo out all the elements, So I was considering a better solution, Anyway, this looks a good solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the error reporting in PHP

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

And send the error logs, you can use them.

else if you want to customized error log

You can use `error_get_last()` this gives you the last error.

```
foreach($array as $element){
  $error_arr = error_get_last();
 //log error in the file and flush on next iterator
  error_clear_last();
}
```

Or use the error reporting tool like [sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) which will send you error + current var values to your email.

Comment: I am assuming i need to write this code in the end of the script, But in that case it would only catch the last error, What if the script throws more than one error

Comment: Yeah, it will catch the last error ! so its better to enable the error reporting, which will log all the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But i haven't understood, how we would know for which element the script is throwing those errors?